# how to make the inside of the circle transparent/opaque in this CSS animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to make the inside of the circle transparent/opaque. 
I've tried adding opacity: 0.7 (similar to my page-overlay) but it doesn't work as it should.

All I want is to have the inside of the circle have the same transparency/opacity effect like the page-overlay.

Any ideas on how it can be done?

Thanks a lot

Here's a link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lgujoo4/

here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>


<style>

#page-overlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999998;
}

.loader {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 5em auto;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  width: 11em;
  height: 11em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000000;
  -webkit-animation: load3 1.4s infinite linear;
  animation: load3 1.4s infinite linear;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
}
.loader:before {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
}
.loader:after {
    background: #000;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes load3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Tbe brown cow jump over the lazy dog.</p>
</div>
        <div class="load-container load3">
            <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
        </div>
<div id="page-overlay" style="display:block;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks transparent to me the black part the quarter circle overlaying is not, is that the one u want to make transparent ?

Comment: looks weird on my screen: http://i.imgur.com/CFig2u3.png. Using OSX Yosemite here but on Chrome and Firefox browsers.

Comment: looks the same as mine, are u trying the make the gray part transparent ?